# Macro to import local .html file to excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet which compares data from a TXT file with a UDL file. These formats import easily into my spreadsheet.

Then I attempted to import a locally stored .html file into this spreadsheet through a macro button, I did not succeed writing my own code nor finding correct code on the internet.

What I need help with:

1. Press button and select a locally stored .HTML file
2. Convert it to xlsx
3. Automatically adding the new xlsx file to a tab in the original spreadsheet.

My .HTML file converts perfectly to xlsx with the code below:

```
Sub Open_HTML_Save_XLSX()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Temp\Example.html"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Temp\Example.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: do you need to do this in a loop, because there exists a solution to import html files using menus, if its just a few files its better to use keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I don't need this in a loop, it is just a single .html file, could you send me your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Alok Singh for your input. I managed to answer my question on my own, sorry for the inconvenience :). posting my answer below

```
Sub Button_click()
Range("A1:s1000").Clear
Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook

OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Your .HTML file ,*.html")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1:s1000").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("a1:s1000").Value


End Sub
```